# Compute $E[ \sqrt{Q} e^{-tQ} ]$ where $Q$ is non-central chi-square random variable.

Tags: probability-theory, expected-value

Let  $Q$  be non-central chi-square random variable of degree $k$ and centrality parameter $\mu$.

How to compute  the following expectation 
\begin{align}
E\left[ \sqrt{Q} e^{-tQ} \right], t>0 
\end{align}

I was thinking this can be computed by using the fact that $Q= \sqrt{ \sum_{i=1}^k Z_i^2 }$ where $Z_i \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_i,1)$ and $\mu= \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^k \mu_i^2}$, and $Z_i$'s are independent.

Using this observation we get that
\begin{align}
E\left[ \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^k Z_i^2 } e^{-t\sum_{i=1}^k Z_i^2 } \right]= E\left[ \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^k Z_i^2 }  \prod_{i=1}^k  e^{-tZ_i^2 } \right].
\end{align} 
However, it is not clear to me how such exressions can be  manipulated or expanded.

I also tried direct integration but expression seem very long, so I stopped.

Comment: I'd work from the [pdf of the non-central chi-square variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncentral_chi-squared_distribution) and integrate. You'll just have to look up some properties of the Bessel functions. Note there is a closed form for the mgf, which is $E[e^{-tQ}]$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\mathbf E\left[ \sqrt{X} e^{-tX}\right] =
e^{-\lambda/2}
(1+2t)^{-(k+1)/2} \sqrt{2}
\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{k+1}{2}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{k}{2}\right)}
{}_1F_1 \left( \frac{k+1}{2}; \frac{k}{2};  \frac{\lambda}{2(1+2t)}\right) 
$$

---

We proceed to show this over a number of steps; first I outline the main claims, and then I will come back to prove the first of these (the rest are referenced below).

We consider a $\chi^2$ variable parameterised by $\lambda > 0$, $k > 0$ with PDF

$$
f(x) = \frac12 e^{-(x+\lambda)/2} \left( \frac{x}{\lambda} \right)^{k/4 -1/2} I_{k/2 -1}(\sqrt{\lambda x}),$$
where $I$ denotes the modified Bessel function of the first kind.

**Claim 1.** *(proof below)* Let $X \sim \chi^2(\lambda,k)$ and $\tilde X \sim \chi^2(\tilde \lambda, k)$, where $\tilde \lambda = \lambda/(1+2t)$. Then

$$ \mathbf E\left[ \sqrt{X} e^{-tX}\right] = \exp\left(- \frac{t}{1+2t}\lambda\right) (1+2t)^{-(k+1)/2} \mathbf E \left[ \sqrt{ \tilde X}\right]  $$

So in particular we have reduced the problem to calculating the expectation of the square root of a non-central chi-squared distribution. To do this we will want to relate the non-central $\chi^2$ distribution to the centralised one with $\lambda = 0$.

**Claim 2.** *(Muirhead, 2005. Corollary 1.3.5)* Let $P \sim \text{Poi}(\lambda/2)$ be Poisson distributed, then
$$\chi^2(\lambda, k) = \chi^2(0,k+2 P).$$
Where the equality is in distribution.

In particular this claim gives us a way to calculate $\mathbf E[\sqrt{\tilde X}]$ by conditionining on $P$:

$$ \mathbf E[ \sqrt{\tilde X}]  = e^{-\tilde \lambda/2} \sum_{p=0}^\infty \frac{(\tilde \lambda/2)^p}{p!}  \mathbf E \left[\sqrt{X^{(k+2p)}}\right]$$
where I have denoted $X^{k} \sim \chi^2(0,k)$ for a centralised chi-squared distribution with $k$ degrees of freedom.

To tie things up we will require one further claim.

**Claim 3.** *(Forbes, Evans, Hastings, Peacock 2011. Chapter 11.3)*
$$ \mathbf E \left[ \sqrt{X^{(k)}} \right] = \sqrt{2} \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{k+1}{2}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{k}{2}\right)}, $$

Piecing all of this together we have the main result:

**Theorem**
$$\mathbf E\left[ \sqrt{X} e^{-tX}\right] =
e^{-\lambda/2}
(1+2t)^{-(k+1)/2} \sqrt{2}
\sum_{p=0}^\infty \frac{\left(\frac{\lambda}{(2(1+2t)}\right)^p}{p!}
\frac{\Gamma\left(p + \frac{k+1}{2}\right)}{\Gamma\left(p + \frac{k}{2}\right)}
$$

The power series can be recognised as a [confluent hypergeometric function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confluent_hypergeometric_function), so we have the following corollary.

**Corollary**
$$\mathbf E\left[ \sqrt{X} e^{-tX}\right] =
e^{-\lambda/2}
(1+2t)^{-(k+1)/2} \sqrt{2}
\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{k+1}{2}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{k}{2}\right)}
{}_1F_1 \left( \frac{k+1}{2}; \frac{k}{2};  \frac{\lambda}{2(1+2t)}\right) 
$$

---

Claims 2 and 3 are referenced above. Therefore I prove only Claim 1.

Following Raskolnikov's suggestion we turn to the PDF of the distribution, defined above. And note

$$ \begin{aligned}
\mathbf E[ \sqrt{X} e^{-tX} ]& = 
\int x^{1/2} e^{-tx}f(x) dx \\
& =  \int x^{1/2} \frac12 e^{-((1+2t)x+\lambda)/2} \left( \frac{x}{\lambda} \right)^{k/4 -1/2} I_{k/2 -1}(\sqrt{\lambda x}) dx.
\end{aligned}
$$
Consider the change of variables $\tilde x = (1+2t)x$ and $\tilde \lambda = \lambda / (1+2t)$, then in particular note that the term in the exponential becomes

$$(1+2t)x + \lambda = \tilde x + (1+2t)\tilde \lambda,$$
whilst
$$\left(\frac{x}{\lambda}\right)^{k/4 - 1/2} = \left(\frac1{(1+2t)^2} \frac{\tilde x}{\tilde \lambda}\right)^{k/4 -1/2} =(1+2t)^{1-k/2} \left(\frac{\tilde x}{\tilde \lambda}\right)^{k/4 -1/2} $$
and
$$ \sqrt{\lambda x} = \sqrt{\tilde \lambda \tilde x}$$

Putting these together we have:
$$ \begin{aligned}
\mathbf E[ \sqrt{X} e^{-tX} ]& = 
(1+2t)^{1-k/2} \int x^{1/2} \frac12  \exp\left(-(\tilde x + (1+2t)\tilde \lambda)/2\right) \left( \frac{\tilde x}{\tilde \lambda} \right)^{k/4 -1/2} I_{k/2 -1}(\sqrt{\tilde \lambda \tilde x}) dx \\
& = (1+2t)^{1-k/2} \exp(-t \tilde \lambda) \int x^{1/2} \frac12  \exp\left(-(\tilde x + \tilde \lambda)/2\right) \left( \frac{\tilde x}{\tilde \lambda} \right)^{k/4 -1/2} I_{k/2 -1}(\sqrt{\tilde \lambda \tilde x}) dx
\end{aligned}
$$
We still have two terms which remain in terms of $x$, rather than $ \tilde x$:

$$ x^{1/2} = (1+2t)^{-1/2} \tilde x,$$
and to complete the change of variables formula

$$ dx = (1+2t)^{-1} d \tilde x.$$

Including these changes of variables we have

$$ \begin{aligned}
\mathbf E[ \sqrt{X} e^{-tX} ]& = 
(1+2t)^{-(k+1)/2} \exp(-t \tilde \lambda) \int \tilde x^{1/2} \frac12  \exp\left(-(\tilde x + \tilde \lambda)/2\right) \left( \frac{\tilde x}{\tilde \lambda} \right)^{k/4 -1/2} I_{k/2 -1}(\sqrt{\tilde \lambda \tilde x}) d \tilde x \\
& = (1+2t)^{-(k+1)/2} \exp(-t \tilde \lambda) \int \tilde x^{1/2} \tilde f(\tilde x) d \tilde x
\end{aligned}
$$
where $\tilde f$ denotes the PDF of the $\chi^2$ with parameters $\tilde \lambda$, and $k$. The result now follows on writing
$$ \exp(-t \tilde \lambda) = \exp(-t\lambda/(1+2t))$$

---

Finally we check the above using a few different methods in `R`.

First we set some arbitrary choices of the parameters

```
t <- 1
lambda <- 2
k <- 2
```

In the first method, we sample $X$ directly as a $\chi^2(\lambda, k)$ distribution.

```
# Sample chi-squared.    
x <- rchisq(10e06, df = k, ncp = lambda)
mean( sqrt(x) * exp(-t *x) )
[1] 0.1436569
```

In the second we apply Claim 1, and sample the $\chi^2(\lambda/(1+2t,k)$ distribution

```
y <- rchisq(10e06, df = k, ncp = lambda/(1+2*t))
mean(sqrt(y)) * exp(- t * lambda/(1+2*t) ) * (1 + 2 *t)^{-(k + 1)/2}
[1] 0.1436606
```

In the third we apply Claim 2 and check that the Poisson weighting formula is correct.

```
df <- data_frame(p = rpois(10e06,lambda/(2*(1+2*t))) ) %>%
  mutate(
    z = rchisq(n(), df = k + 2 * p,ncp=0)
  )

mean(sqrt(df$z)) * exp(- t * lambda/(1 + 2 *t) ) * (1 + 2 *t)^{-(k + 1)/2}
[1] 0.1436255
```

Finally we compute the formula presented in the theorem statement.

```
library(CharFun) # Required for hypergeom1F1 function
exp(-lambda/2) *(1+2*t)^{-(k+1)/2} * sqrt(2) * gamma((k+1)/2) / gamma(k/2) * hypergeom1F1(lambda/(2*(1+2*t)), (k+1)/2, k/2)
[1] 0.1436613
```

Answer (score -1):

Mathematica 11.3.0 produces

```
Mean[TransformedDistribution[Sqrt[x]*Exp[-t*x],x \[Distributed] 
 NoncentralChiSquareDistribution[k, \[Mu]],  Assumptions -> t > 0]]
```

> $$\sqrt{2} e^{-\frac{\mu }{2}} (2 t+1)^{-\frac{k}{2}-\frac{1}{2}} \Gamma \left(\frac{k+1}{2}\right) \, _1\tilde{F}_1\left(\frac{k+1}{2};\frac{k}{2};\frac{\mu }{4 t+2}\right) $$

Edit. Thanks to @owen88 who paid my attention to the typo in my code:`x*Exp[-t*x]` instead of `Sqrt[x]*Exp[-t*x]`. Fixed.

Comment: Votes down should be motivated. BTW, could the down-voter derive this formula by hand?

Comment: Interestingly I don't seem to be able to derive this as a special case of the formula I give above; do you think Mathematica may be using different notation conventions? As an example at $t = 0$, $\lambda = 0$ this is equivalent to the expectation of a $\chi(k)$ distribution, which equals $$\sqrt{2} \frac{\Gamma((k+1)/2)}{\Gamma(k/2)}.$$ My formula is consistent with this, whereas the Mathematica gives the answer $k$. This doesn't seem to be because your solution is for $t>0$ as both formulae are continuous as $t \downarrow 0$.

Comment: @owen88: If $t=0$, then the distribution coincides with the noncentral $\chi^2$-distribution which mean equals $k+\mu$. That's OK. Your " both formulae are continuous" is not based.

Comment: Aha, I've just realised the discrepancy: you've computed $$ \mathbf{E}[X e^{-tX}],$$whereas the question asked for $$ \mathbf{E}[\sqrt{X} e^{-tX}].$$ This will explain the difference in our answers (and the reason you refer to $\chi^2$ not $\chi$ in your comment above).

Comment: ... And then using Corollary 1 in my post, its pretty clear how one can then derive your formula for $\mathbf E[X e^{-tX}]$ from the known facts of the $\chi^2$ distribution (as you refer to above, regarding the mean).

Comment: @owen88: You are right.

Comment: This still does not look quite right; at $\lambda = 0$, $t = 0$ this simplifies to $$\sqrt{2} \Gamma\left(\frac{k+1}{2}\right),$$ which is missing a factor of $\Gamma\left(\frac{k}{2}\right)^{-1}$ compared to my answer, and the answer you'd expect based on the expectation of a $\chi$ distribution.

Comment: @owen88: You are not right: the evaluation r /.{ \ [Mu] -> 0, t -> 0 }, where r is the MMA result, produces $$ \frac{\sqrt{2} \Gamma \left(\frac{k+1}{2}\right)}{\Gamma \left(\frac{k}{2}\right)}$$

Comment: What am I not right about? I believe the formula that you provide simplifies to the expression I provided above (missing the second $\Gamma$ term); is this what you are questioning? Or are you saying that your formula is discontinuous at $t=0$, and hence why our answers do not agree?

Comment: @owen88 The formulas are the same, it's just that the notation is not explained; ${\widetilde F}$ denotes a regularized hypergeometric function, that is, a ${_pF_q}$ divided by $\Gamma(b_1) \cdot \ldots \cdot \Gamma(b_q)$.

Comment: That explains it; hadn't noticed the tilde. Thanks.