# Simplify double sum

Tags: normal-distribution, gaussian-integral

Does the following expression has a closed form
\begin{align}
E \left[ \| Z\|^k \exp(t \|Z\|^2)\right] 
\end{align}
for $k$ is even and $Z$ is standard normal vector.

For the case of $k=2$ the computation is very easy.  For $k=1/2$  see here [Compute $E[ \sqrt{Q} e^{-tQ} ]$ where $Q$ is non-central chi-square random variable.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2973590/compute-e-sqrtq-e-tq-where-q-is-non-central-chi-square-random-varia).

However, this question is about even $k$.  I there a way to use a binomina theorem to solve this ?

Answer (score 1):

In hyperspherical coordinates in $\mathbb R^n$, the integral becomes
$$\operatorname E \left[ \lVert Z \rVert^k e^{t \lVert Z \rVert^2} \right] =
(2 \pi)^{-n/2} S_{n - 1} \int_0^\infty
 \rho^{k + n - 1} e^{t \rho^2 - \rho^2/2} d\rho = \\
2^{k/2} (1 - 2 t)^{(-k - n)/2} \left( \frac n 2 \right)_{k/2},$$
where $S_n$ is the surface area of a unit $n$-sphere and $(n)_k$ is the rising factorial.

Comment: Thanks. Can you talk more about the change of variable?

Comment: We integrate $\lVert x \rVert^k e^{t \lVert x \rVert^2} f_Z(x)$ over $\mathbb R^n$, $x = (x_1, \dots, x_n)$. The [Jacobian of the coordinate transformation to spherical coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere#Spherical_volume_element) also gives the area element of a sphere of radius $\rho$, therefore integrating the Jacobian over the spherical angles gives the area of the sphere; $\lVert x \rVert$ and $f_Z(x)$ depend only on $\rho$.