# Is there an incomplete confluent hypergeometric function of the first kind?

Tags: probability-theory, partial-differential-equations

I started with the expected value of the square root of a chi-squared random variable, topic covered here:

[Compute $E[ \sqrt{Q} e^{-tQ} ]$ where $Q$ is non-central chi-square random variable.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2973590/compute-e-sqrtq-e-tq-where-q-is-non-central-chi-square-random-varia)

$$\mathbf E\left[ \sqrt{X} e^{-tX}\right] =
e^{-\lambda/2}
(1+2t)^{-(k+1)/2} \sqrt{2}
\sum_{p=0}^\infty \frac{\left(\frac{\lambda}{(2(1+2t)}\right)^p}{p!}
\frac{\Gamma\left(p + \frac{k+1}{2}\right)}{\Gamma\left(p + \frac{k}{2}\right)}
$$

Thing is I would need the expected value with the random variable greater than some positive value $$ \alpha $$rather than zero. My hand derivation seems to lead to an infinite series where instead of ratios of gamma functions, I would have ratios of upper incomplete gamma functions.

$$\mathbf E\left[ \sqrt{X} e^{-tX}\right] =
e^{-\lambda/2}
(1+2t)^{-(k+1)/2} \sqrt{2}
\sum_{p=0}^\infty \frac{\left(\frac{\lambda}{(2(1+2t)}\right)^p}{p!}
\frac{\Gamma\left(p + \frac{k+1}{2},\alpha\right)}{\Gamma\left(p + \frac{k}{2}, \alpha\right)}
$$

A series of plain gamma function ratios seems to be a "confluent hypergeometric function". I've searched but didn't find anything, so maybe anyone can help me, is there such a thing as "incomplete confluent hypergeometric function"? I found some papers on "incomplete Pochhammer ratios" but no closed-form expression like for confluent hypergeometric function.

It seems to me a stretch to call these things "closed-form expression" but as long as there's some math library computing them, I guess we can call them that. For the confluent hypergeometric function I found this: https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/doc/html/specfunc.htm

So question again summarized: does there exist a confluent hypergeometric function but with incomplete gamma functions instead? Is there a math library that computes them, or at least some paper I could look at?

Comment: The Marcum Q-function has an incomplete gamma function in the numerator of the summand.  I haven't seen anything with an  incomplete gamma function in the denominator.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, I'll have a look.